# sort by nested value in object array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort a object array depending on whether it has contains a nested value or not. I messed around with using _.sortBy, reduce and sort but nothing was really working for me.

here is my set of data:

```
const impacts = [{

impactAreas: [{
      name: "development"
    }, {
      name: "education"
    }],
  },
  {

    impactAreas: [{
      name: "education"
    }],
  },
  {
    impactAreas: [{
      name: "development"
    }, {
      name: "politics"
    }],
  },
  {
    impactAreas: [{
      name: "politics"
    }, {
      name: "education"
    }]
  }
]

function getImpacts(impacts) {
  impacts.forEach(
    impact => impact.impactAreas.reduce((acc, impactArea) => {
      if (impactArea.name === 'politics') {
        console.log(yes)
        return [impactArea, ...acc]
      }
      return [...acc, impactArea];
    }, [])
  )
}
```

In this example i was trying to sort by whether or not the object contained 'politics' but is returning undefined.

Here is my jfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ycrpaLn5/1/

Thanks!

Comment: please add the result after sorting as well.

Comment: right now i am just receiving undefined.

Comment: Can you please post a full snippet of how you are expecting the result to look after the transformation/sorting has been completed.

Comment: Sort by `.impactAreas.length`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to move all items with `politics` to top, then you vould use a check for the nested array and take a delta of the checks as return value for sorting.

```js
var impacts = [{ impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "politics" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "politics" }, { name: "education" }] }],
    POLITICS = ({ name }) => name === 'politics';

impacts.sort(({ impactAreas: a }, { impactAreas: b }) =>
    b.some(POLITICS) - a.some(POLITICS));

console.log(impacts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about politics at the top, reduce the array into an array with politics (1st), and one without, and then concatenate them:

```js
const impacts = [{ impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "politics" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "politics" }, { name: "education" }] }];

const hasPolitics = ({ impactAreas }) => 
  impactAreas.some(({ name }) => name === 'politics');

const result = [].concat(...impacts.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[hasPolitics(o) ? 0 : 1].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, [[], []]));

console.log(result);
```

If you don't need to preserve the original order, you can add items that has politics to the start of the reduce accumulator:

```js
const impacts = [{ impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "education" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "development" }, { name: "politics" }] }, { impactAreas: [{ name: "politics" }, { name: "education" }] }];

const hasPolitics = ({ impactAreas }) => 
  impactAreas.some(({ name }) => name === 'politics');

const result = impacts.reduce((r, o) =>
  hasPolitics(o) ? [o, ...r] : [...r, o]
, []);

console.log(result);
```